# Only pass function parameters if they exist

Tags: python, function

I have python3 class function defined like below:

```
class class1:
    def funcOne(self, reqvar1, reqVar2, optVar1=default1, optVar2=default2, optVar3="server.domain", optVar4="defaultUser", optVar5="<default_Flags>"):
```

It gets called (I want to call it like this rather) in the main program like:

```
argsIn=argparser.parse_args()

classInst=class1()
classInst.funcOne(5, 12, argsIn.inVal1, argsIn.inVal2, argsIn.inVal3, argsIn.inVal4, argsIn.inVal5)
```

args.inVal[1-5] are optional on the command line when running. If they don't get supplied I want the class function to use the defaults, if they do get supplied then they would use the supplied values.

Currently if they are not supplied on the command line, inVal[1-5] are passed as 'None' which overwrite the actual default values.

The class function is maintained separately and they manage the defaults. Putting them into my script (for example in the argparser options) is not appropriate.

Is there a way to easily work with this situation that doesn't resort to:

```
if args.inVal1 and not args.inVal2...
if not args.inVal1 and args.inVal2 and not args.inVal3...
```

as the number of combinations gets large.

It seems like it should be simple, but I am not connecting something here.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: take a look at `**kwargs` it should help you solve your problem easily ^^. Your function definition would look like `def funcOne(self, reqvar1, reqvar2, **kwargs)` where `**kwargs` can be used as a `dict` and contain a variable amount of named parameters... You would then do for example `kwargs.get('optVar1', None)` . If `optVar1` does not exist, it would return `None`.

Comment: I am aware of that, but unfortunately I don't control the class/function and can't make changes (I can suggest, but where it goes, I don't know).
Can I used something like **kwargs simply on my side and have it still work with the original definition?

Comment: If you define your own function with `**kwargs` but you still use that precise `funcOne` function, that would result the same problem for the comparison :/

Comment: I'm afraid there's not best way to do that than with `if`statement because of the current function definition.
At least if there is not `optVar1` param you know that you can't have any other.. (or it would not make sense to use default values).  And same in case you have `optVar1` but not `optVar2`  you know that `optVar[2-5]` cannot exist...

Comment: @Flo
I was afraid of that. I might see if I can get the function changed first.
Your statement about the optVars are is not necessarily true.
This funciton call is valid:
funcOne(reqVar1=5, reqVar2=12, optVar4="roUser")
So I have to assume that any optVar can exist independently or in any combination.
Logic wise, some of the optional values would have to be defined in some pairs (user and password for example) for practical purposes, but there are still a lot of combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a dictionary that contains the optional variable names, you can pass that dictionary to the function call. I only commented out the argparser for testing.

```
class class1:
    def funcOne(self, reqvar1, reqVar2, optVar1='default1', optVar2='default2', optVar3="server.domain", optVar4="defaultUser", optVar5="<default_Flags>"):
        print(optVar1)
        print(optVar2)
        print(optVar3)
        print(optVar4)
        print(optVar5)

#argsIn=argparser.parse_args()

optionalArgs = {'optVar1': 'TestingVar1',   #args.inVal1,
                'optVar2': None,            #args.inVal2,
                'optVar3': 'TestingVar3',   #args.inVal3,
                'optVar4': None,            #args.inVal4,
                'optVar5': None}            #args.inVal5}
optionalArgsClean = {k:v for k, v in optionalArgs.items() if v is not None}

classInst=class1()
classInst.funcOne(5, 12, **optionalArgsClean)
```

Running the above code produces:

```
TestingVar1
default2
TestingVar3
defaultUser
<default_Flags>
```